# Convert big-endian bytes array to int like struct.unpack in python

Tags: python, c++

Recently i'm tring to convert a python serial data analyzer into c++,but i face a problem that how can i convert `feff` to an integer -2 in c++,and this is a part of my python code.

```
def Control_Message(input_):
    print(input_[4:8])
    print(bytes.fromhex(input_[4:8]))
    print(struct.unpack('h', bytes.fromhex(input_[4:8])))
    print(struct.unpack('h', bytes.fromhex(input_[4:8]))[0])
    Angular_Rate_X = struct.unpack('h', bytes.fromhex(input_[0:4]))[0] * 600 * 2 ** -20
```

and the result is:

```
feff
b'\xfe\xff'
(-2,)
-2
```

and now i'm confusing that how can i do the same thing in c++,hope for your help,thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking for examples of doing this in your C++ textbook? What have you tried? Examples of basic byte manipulations of this kind are always found in introductory C and C++ textbooks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for you anwser!i try to google this solution but i failed.Exactly i'm new to c++,and i'll go to check my c primer right now,

Comment: @Kniok  When you convert feff to an integer, you get 65279. Can you explain a little more what you mean by trying to convert it to 2?

Comment: @east1000 Exactly this is a 2's complement...i never think of this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint16_t value = 0xfeff;
    uint8_t firstByte = static_cast<uint8_t>((value & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    uint8_t secondByte = static_cast<uint8_t>(value & 0x00FF);
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(firstByte) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(secondByte) << "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
fe
ff
```

If your goal is to get fe and ff separately and then see them as integers, do as follows.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint16_t value = 0xfeff;
    uint8_t firstByte = static_cast<uint8_t>((value & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    uint8_t secondByte = static_cast<uint8_t>(value & 0x00FF);
    std::cout  << static_cast<int>(firstByte) << "\n";
    std::cout  << static_cast<int>(secondByte) << "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
254
255
```

If your goal is to find the integer value for feff  then do the following

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint16_t value = 0xfeff;
    std::cout  << static_cast<int>(value) << "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
65279
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!I found what i need is a little-endian complementary code calculation instead of simple convert.And now i have got the solution!

Comment: @Kniok You are welcome, I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as the answer to your question so that other people can better benefit from the answer.